# How can i make this awesome clouds effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Im trying to find out a way to colour these clouds but im just getting close. still something is missing.

[image]

I tried with gradient map and it seems that it just not enough.
Im looking to get the exact effect. if you have any idea it’ll be awesome,

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing your desired outcome but you should really [edit] this to show your own work as well wherever it is you got stuck so we can help you with the next step.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate... Deja vu?

Answer (score 4):

Not everything is as simple as adding a gradient, in this image there is a photomontage job, looking in detail each area it's easy to find some repetition patterns

[image]

Starting from a background image, you can achieve color effects by superimposing images, adding gaussian blur, experimenting with layers blending modes, opacities, masks and grouped effect layers.

In this quick example:

- Blending modes: Vivid Light and Difference
- Hue and Saturation to change each color layer

[image]

Images from unsplash: [clouds](https://unsplash.com/photos/8iZG31eXkks), [colors](https://unsplash.com/photos/7lAz-CrlED0)

Comment: Thanks Danielillo! I really appreciate your help. ill try this method